# añadir clase según url

Tags: css

estimados quiero añadir una clase a una etiqueta A según su url tengo esta idea que se adapta bien a  lo que necesito pero no logro hacerla funcionar me dan una mano.
Gracias

```js
switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case '/technology.html':
        $('nav a').addClass('tecnologia')
    case '/something.html':
        $('nav a').addClass('some')
}
```

Comment: Te sale algún error o simplemente las clases no se agregan ? Dinos exactamente que es lo que sucede

Comment: y que pasa?, revisaste con el inspector del navegador, si llega a adicionarle la clase o no?

Comment: no se agregan las clases, ya revise el inspector no se añaden las clases

Comment: ¿Si imprimes el valor de `window.location.pathname` si imprime los valores esperados?

Answer (score 0):

Trata de verificar que `window.location.pathname` trae exactamente los valores que colocas en cada uno de los `case`, además veo que tienes un error en tu `switch` y es que te falta agregar el `break` a cada `case`:

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case '/technology.html':
        $('nav a').addClass('tecnologia')
    break;
    case '/something.html':
        $('nav a').addClass('some')
    break;
}
```

Posiblemente ese sea el error !

> Cuando quieres capturar el **href** de cada `<a>` y no la **url** del **browser** debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var etiquetas = $('nav a');

for(var i = 0; i < etiquetas.length; i++){
    var url = $(etiquetas[i]).attr('href');

    switch (url) {
        case '/technology.html':
            $(etiquetas[i]).addClass('tecnologia')
        break;
        case '/something.html':
            $(etiquetas[i]).addClass('some')
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya funciona pero creo que he cometido un error, lo que deseo es añadir un clase a un etiqueta a según la url que se obtiene en el href no en la url, pues es un menu que hay que añadirle un icono según el nombre de la url que esta en el href se añade la clase.

Comment: te voy a añadir una edición a la respuesta para que veas como sería el proceso con el nuevo requerimiento que pides.

Comment: Ya te edité la respuesta, espero te sirva